# How to slide images with name in half circular path

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I developed a page in html includes two vertical sliders.I need to integrate a half circular slider in my page.Is there any plugin or code for doing same.

Here is my page

[image]

Comment: There is no perfect way to set the images in circular path...use margins for that. or use position: absolute and set  the left and right values.

Comment: But I need to scroll on these images dynamically..

Comment: Yes, we can do it easily...just check this demonstration: https://s18.postimg.org/ezifgkg15/circular_images.png

Comment: If the list has more than six images , I need a scroll from bottom for seeing the next image.

Comment: I can give the clue..just use any jQuery "vertical thumbnail slider" and set thumbs positions as a half circular path like I show you in the screenshot for slides...once try this method.